# Bootstrap Carousel Indicators Won't Cycle On Custom WordPress Theme

Tags: php, jquery, javascript, html, twitter-bootstrap

***UPDATE - This wasn't showing because of a cache issue. The comment referencing changing the jQuery to :first-child instead of :first was indeed the only issue that needed to be addressed. ***

I am creating a WordPress theme and the image slider fails to do three things:

1) When clicking an indicator it does not do anything.

2) The image slider does not slide automatically.

3) The first indicator is never on.

I know the content is present because if I add a Post with the Category slider the image will display along with the title and a new carousel indicator. I also checked the DOM and all of the data-slides are there but nothing is moving. Any help is appreciated.

**HTML/PHP**

```
<?php 
   $number = 0; 
   query_posts('category_name=slider'); 
   if(have_posts()):  
?>

<div id="carousel-example-generic" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
  <ol class="carousel-indicators">
    <?php while(have_posts()): the_post(); ?>
      <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="<?php echo $number++; ?>"></li>
      <?php endwhile; ?>
  </ol>

  <!-- Carousel items -->
  <div class="carousel-inner">  

    <?php while(have_posts()): the_post(); ?>

    <div class="item">
      <?php $image = wp_get_attachment_image_src( get_post_thumbnail_id ( $post->ID ), 'single-post-thumbnail' ); ?><a href=#"><img class="img-responsive" src="<?php echo $image[0]; ?>" />
      <div class="carousel-caption">
        <?php the_title();?>  
      </div>
    </div></a>
    <?php endwhile; ?>
  </div>
</div>

<?php endif; wp_reset_query(); ?>
```

**jQuery**

```
//Carousel Indicator
$(".carousel-indicators li:first-child").addClass("active");
$(".carousel-inner .item:first-child").addClass("active");
```

Comment: do you have 'wp_head()' and 'wp_footer()' in your theme at the corresponding locations?

Comment: <?php wp_head(); ?> is the last line in the <head> and <?php wp_footer(); ?> is in the footer.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding :first-child over :first solved the indicator issue but the above code is actually correct. I had to clear the cache and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

From where I see it you are looping the indicators as well as your carousel inner items. Basically, try looping the content only.

Comment: Hi, could you be more specific? Do you mean remove: <?php while(have_posts()): the_post(); ?>
      <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="<?php echo $number++; ?>"></li>
      <?php endwhile; ?>